# Daily sums for a range of years

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, aggregate-functions

The code below returns daily sums for a range of years. I would like to add the constraint to the COGS column `WHERE IVENTORY.CONSIGNMENT = "No"`.  I tried adding a subquery but everthing I tried resulted in an error. How should a subquery be coded to work with the following code?

```
SELECT a.[Month / Day / Year],
       Round(Sum(a.[COGS]), 2) AS COGS
FROM
  (SELECT Format(DatePart("m", sale_date), "00") & "/" & Format(DatePart("d", sale_date), "00") & "/" & DatePart("yyyy", sale_date) AS [Month / Day / Year],
          Format(DatePart("d", s.sale_date), "00") AS [Sale Day],
          Format(DatePart("m", s.sale_date), "00") AS [Sale Month],
          DatePart("yyyy", s.sale_date) AS [Sale Year],
          Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE, 0)*Nz(s.quantity, 0) AS COGS
   FROM INVENTORY AS i
   INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT AS s ON i.INVENTORY_ID = s.INVENTORY_ID
   WHERE DatePart("yyyy", sale_date) BETWEEN 2000 AND 2100) AS a
GROUP BY a.[Month / Day / Year],
         a.[Sale Month],
         a.[Sale Day],
         a.[Sale Year]
ORDER BY a.[Sale Year],
         a.[Sale Month],
         a.[Sale Day];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've correctly understood your requirements, I believe you can accomplish this without the use of the subquery, e.g.:

```
select 
    format(s.sale_date,"mm/dd/yyyy") as [Month / Day / Year],
    round(sum(nz(i.vendor_actual_price, 0)*nz(s.quantity, 0)),2) as COGS
from
    inventory i inner join sales_receipt s on i.inventory_id = s.inventory_id
where
    i.consignment = 'No' and 
    year(s.sale_date) between 2000 and 2100
group by
    format(s.sale_date,"mm/dd/yyyy"), s.sale_date
order by
    s.sale_date
```